# get ceil value of number when divided in struts tag

Tags: java, jsp, math, struts2, ceil

I am using struts iterator for displaying my array list I had to put a condition in the `end` attribute of the iterator tag. how to get the CEIL value when two integers are divided. if array list size is 3 then I need to get output as 2 for end attribute

```
<s:iterator var="counter" begin="0" end="arraylist.size()/2 " >
   /*my code...*/
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: This might help:
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Number.html

Comment: %{java.lang.Math.ceil(arraylist.size()/2)}

Comment: not able to use the above...getting an exception

Comment: where is your arraylist defined? can you post that? is that a variable on your java side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `size` method return type is `int` and the `end` attribute of `<s:iterator>` eventually will be cast to `Integer` you can simple add `1` to the size of array list before dividing it and you get same result as using `Math.ceil`.

```
<s:iterator var="counter" begin="0" end="(arraylist.size()+1)/2">

</s:iterator>
```

BTW if you decide to enable `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess` which is **not** recommended and use `Math.ceil` method in JSP you need to indicate that you are dividing by a double value (e.g. `2d`) or it will be converted to `int` before passing it to `ceil`.

```
<s:iterator var = "counter" begin = "0" 
            end = "@java.lang.Math@ceil(arraylist.size()/2d)">

</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

In struts.xml

```xml
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

Now it is possible to call static methods; the syntax, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13084571/1654265), would be:

```xml
@java.lan.Math@ceil()
```

and then

```xml
<s:iterator var = "counter" 
          begin = "0" 
            end = "%{@java.lang.Math@ceil(arraylist.size()/2)}" >

</s:iterator>
```

Obviously you need in the action a property named like that (the naming choice is no good at all, if it is the real name)

```xml
private List<Object> arraylist;
```

with obviously its getter (`getArraylist()`) .

Answer (score 0):

When two integers are divided you get a rational number. So, to get rid of the fractional part you can cast it to `int`.

```
int length = (int) arraylist.size()/2;
```

Use this result in your iterator.